Как создать в убунту диск, который будет доступен пользователям винды по ip?
Как создать в убунту диск, который будет доступен пользователям винды по ip?

возможный дубликат

Чтобы открыть доступ к данным на Ubuntu из Windows,можно использовать варианты:

Использовать FTP-сервер.
Установить и настроить SAMBA-сервер.
Я не использовал, но есть возможность, получить доступ к данным через WebDAV или NFS (Network File System).
Если Windows10 и старше, можно скачивать файлы по SSH с помощью SCP.

